# Joining 2 dataframes on a specific column with IDs

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes (pandas/python) - see image. I am trying to combine dataframes 1 & 2 to produce dataframe 3, joining on the 'record_id' columns.

Any ideas how to do this using pandas?

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge)

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='record_ID', how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks for this - one possible elaboration - what if the values in 'record_ID' of DF1 are unique and DF1 contains other columns of data? It seems that this method seems to replicate the values in those columns by replicating the records.